# Obj-c tableview изменение данных в нём, при "перелистывании", pagecontoller

Tags: slider, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

Здравствуйте.

Начал изучать xcode и obj-c недавно, сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой: как сделать, чтобы при "перелистывании" (ну там что-то вроде слайда), менялись данные в таблице?

На данный момент имею tableview, в который грузятся данные (с сайта, 6 типа данных, 4 данных отображаются в таблице в ячейка, а другие для сортировки, как бы надо выборку, что ли). Эти данные он отображает, но проблема в том, что когда "листаешь", в каждой странице одни и те же данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перелистывание это прокрутка таблички? Покажите код где вы данные выводите, скорее всего это метод `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, будет проще сказать в чем дело. Хотя есть одна более-менее стандартная ошибка с переиспользованием, проверьте не вот так ли у вас выглядит код создания ячейки и заполнения ее данными:

```
static NSString *ident = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell  = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident ];
if(!cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:ident ];
    // вот тут часто пишут присвоение каких-либо данных, а оно не должно быть внутри этого if - таблице по факту достаточно тех ячеек что на экране + еще пару и как только она их наберет, метод dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier начнет выдавать ячейки и программа не будет попадать в присвоение вообще, результат как у вас - все ячейки  повторяются кроме первых, скажем, 8 (число может варьироваться от размера таблицы и ячейки)

}
return cell;
```